# How to find poles and singularities of $f(z) = \frac{\text {ln}(1+z)}{z(e^{iz}-1)} $

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find poles and singularities of

$$ f(z) = \frac{\text {ln}(1+z)}{z(e^{iz}-1)} $$

I already know the poles since I have the problem's answer ($z_k = 2\pi k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$), and I can check it is true, but how by seeing this expression can we deduce there is no singularites and only poles of order one ? What steps lead to the result ?

Comment: What about $z = -1$?

Comment: Well the given correction might be wrong (would not be the first time), and indeed now I don't know how to handle this point z=-1 :/ Is it an essential singularity ?

Comment: If you are taking a branch cut for Log along the negative real axis, it would explain why -1 is missing.